Low traffic in instagrapi python
I'm using the Instagrapi library in Python to automate my Instagram profiles, but I'm using a proxy and the internet cost is very high. I wanted a way to spend as little internet as possible on each function, in order to reduce costs. costs. How I do?
I've already tried using a delay_range, using sessions like dump_settings and load_settings and other workarounds, but without results.
